# Как работает &0[hello]?

Tags: c, c++

Нашел в поддерживаемом коде пример обращения к массиву n[a], где n - индекс, а a - массив. В простом примере выглядит как

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    char hello[] = "hello";

    puts(&0[hello]);
}
```

Вот эта строчка **&0[hello]** - что она значит?!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Стандарт C явно разрешает такую адресацию.

> ##### 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting
>
> <...>
> A postfix expression followed by an
> expression in square brackets `[]` is a
> subscripted designation of an element
> of an array object.
> The definition of
> the subscript operator `[]` is that
> **`E1[E2]`** is identical to **`(*((E1)+(E2)))`**.
> <...>

Для чего это сделано сказать сложно. Скорее всего, хотели максимально упростить адресацию, соответственно, не стали городить сложных структур и определили операцию получения элемента массива как разыменование суммы. Поскольку «плюсик» коммутативен, как следствие желания упростить, получился такой курьёз.

Я не могу придумать ни одного случая, когда был бы оправдан подобный «переворот» операндов.

Answer (score 4):

насколько помню, это эквивалентно &hello[0]. просто кто-то выпендрился.
это передача адреса 0-ого элемента массива (строки char) в функцию puts.
далее по референсу:

> int puts ( const char * str );
>
> Write string to stdout
> Writes the C string pointed by str to stdout and appends a newline character.

Comment: А почему это так? Почему С допускает такой синтаксис?

Comment: ну просто.. захотели так и сделали. может кому-то удобно показалось..
не думаю, что в этом была какая-то техническая необходимость.

Comment: Потому что 1[hello] = (1 + hello) и hello[1] = (hello + 1) одно и то же. Представьте, что 1 - не константа, а переменная. Смысл запрещать один из вариантов? С тем же успехом можно вообще запретить оператор []. И заставить пользователя пользоваться указательной арифметикой:
hello[1] = x; эквивалентно *(hello + 1) = x;

Comment: "Представьте, что 1 - не константа, а переменная." - представил. Все равно не пойму, зачем нужен такой синтаксис.

Answer (score 3):

Просто адрес элемента вычисляется сложением индекса и адреса первого элемента.

Си допускает подобный синтаксис. **UPD**: стёр фигню.

Comment: Если индекс и адрес просто складываются, то как быть если элементы больше байта? Тогда необходимо умножить индекс на sizeof элемента. В приведённом внизу отрывке нет умножения на sizeof. Значит скорее всего будет работать только для однобайтовых. Ща скомпиляю, проверю.

Comment: Да, моё предположение не верно.

Comment: Жёсткий треш. А как, позвашему, работало бы банальное *(hello+3)? Ваще-то операцию прибавления константы к указателю не дураки придумывали…

Comment: тьфу блин, здесь же размер типа указателя учитывается, точно.

Answer (score 1):

```
&0[hello] = &(*(0+hello)) = 0+hello (операция & обратна операции *) = hello
```

Итого можно было написать не puts(&0[hello]); а просто puts(hello);

Answer (score 1):

Все очень просто. Как мы знаем, компилятор видит `hello[0]` иначе. Он это интепритирует в `*(hello + 0)`. Значит, такая запись `&hello[0]` будет выглядеть так `&(*(hello + 0))`.

От перестановки слагаемых сумма не меняется, значит
`*(hello + 0) == *(0 + hello)` и `&(*(hello + 0)) == &(*(0 + hello))`

---

Идем дальше
`*(hello + 0) == hello[0]` и `*(0 + hello) == 0[hello]`

---

`&hello[0] == &(*(data+0))` и `&0[hello] == &(*(0+data))`

---

Ну и это адрес первого елемента то есть `&0[hello] == hello`

Comment: Если вы ссылаетесь на общее правило по поводу перестановки слагаемых, вы неявно предполагаете, что `hello + 0` вычисляется как «адрес `hello` плюс 0». А для случая `hello + 1` было бы «адрес `hello` плюс 1». Это не так для случая, когда тип элемента массива не однобайтный. Правильная формула — `&hello[i] = &hello + i * sizeof(T)`, где `T` — тип элемента массива. В такой формулировке ни о какой перестановке слагаемых речь идти не может.

Comment: @VladD, или я чего-то не понял, или вы написали неправду. Верная формула `&hello[i] == hello + i`. Компилятор сам "домножает" i на sizeof(T), чтобы вычислить адрес.

Comment: @dzhioev: В этом смысле да. Моё вычисление относится к конкретным числам, адресам. Смотрите, если компилятор в выражении `hello + i` домножает второе слагаемое на `sizeof(T)`, мы получаем в смысле физических адресов `hello + i * sizeof(T)`. Если переставить слагаемые (`i + hello`), получится в смысле физических адресов `i + hello * sizeof(hello)` (мы умножили на размер **второго** слагаемого), верно? А это очевидный нонсенс.